# How to integrate font in PowerPoint 2011

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I want to import specific font in PowerPoint, but I don't know how...

The powerpoint file would be send to another computer, so, if possible, I want integrate the font directly in the powerpoint file.

Any help appreciate! Thank

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only the Windows version of PPT can embed fonts and only the Windows version can use fonts that have been embedded.  Mac is totally out of the loop here.

On Windows, only Truetype fonts can be embedded (ie, not Type1) and then only those that the manufacturer permits to be embedded.

PPT's warnings when you try to save a file with fonts embedded are weak; they tell you that a font couldn't be embedded, but not WHICH font, or why.

Peter's screenshot shows you how to embed a font; note though that if you choose the "Embed all characters" option, recipients will be able to edit the text in the file, not just view it.  Assuming embedding the font is permitted, of course.  Embedding all characters will make the PPT file grow by roughly the size of the font file.  I'd avoid embedding Arial Unicode.

Is a font embeddable?  Go to Control Panel | Fonts and locate the font file.
Right-click it, choose Properties.
Go to the Details tab, look for "Font embeddability:"

Installable (fairly rare) means that the font can be embedded and when your file is opened by the recipient, it'll be installed on their system and will be usable not only in your PPT but by any other document/program on their computer.

Editable means that the font can be embedded and used to view or edit the file in which it's embedded on the recipient's system (but won't be usable by other programs or, I believe, documents on the same PC).

Preview/Print means that the font can be used to view or print the document on the recipient's system but not to edit text.  If one of these fonts is embedded, PPT should open the document read-only (but allow the user to substitute a different font if they wish).

There.  More than you EVER wanted to know.

Answer (score 3):

Go into File -> Options. Click the "Save" tab on the left. Tick the box for "Embed fonts in the file" (circled in the screenshot below.

So long as there's no need to edit the file on the other computer, this should allow text in any font to appear identical on both computers.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since Powerpoint for Mac doesn’t embed fonts into presentations (unlike Powerpoint for Microsoft Windows), you are going to have to use an app for this.

Currently, there is only one app on the Mac App Store that can do this for you (Please correct me if I’m wrong).

Presentation Font Embedder is a tool which will walk through the fonts in the Presentation’s slides and will embed suitable ones into the PPTX file accordingly.

You can find the app over here:
https://itunes.apple.com/app/presentation-font-embedder/id1032355479?ls=1&mt=12

Disclosure- I am the developer of Presentation Font Embedder.

Please feel free to ask me any question you have using this link:
http://www.presentationfontembedder.com/ask-us-a-question

BR,
Sahar Radomsky

Comment: Thank you for including disclosure in your answer. For future reference, be sure to read [this page](http://superuser.com/help/promotion) to ensure that your posts are not flagged as spam.